# Translating data query into Domain Relational Calculus

Tags: calculus, data-analysis

Given a following table named BOOKING, which contains three columns, **guest_name, room_number and booking_date**, how do I find the all the **guest_name** that have the same **room_number** and **booking_date**?

I am unsure how to compare data within the same table  (since I am comparing one **room_number** to another **room_number**, and likewise for **booking_date**)

Sadly, all I can muster out is so far is { (Xguest_name) | ...? }

Comment: This may be a better fit for [dba.se]: see http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=relational+calculus

Comment: thank you for the redirect!!! I'll try my question there